# Counter_cache with polymorphic and a regular belongs_to association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I have a User model that `has_many :questions` and a Question both `belongs_to :user` and `belongs_to :expert, as polymorphic: true`. An expert can be a Trainer or a Doctor

I need a counter cache for both `User` and the Trainer and Doctor.

```
class Question < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :expert, polymorphic: true

  has_many :answers, dependent: :destroy
end

class User
  has_many :questions
  has_many :answers, as: :responder
end

class Trainer
  has_many :questions, as: :expert
end

class Doctor
  has_many :questions, as: :expert
end
```

Is it possible to set up `counter_cache` for both `belongs_to :user` and `belongs_to :expert, polymorphic: true`?

This way I could do both `user.questions_count` and `trainer.questions_count`

Answer (score 2):

For user, counter_cache can work normally. You can achieve required for polymorphic association for `Rails-5` using below (using custom counter cache noted [here](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html)),

```
class Question < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, counter_cache: true
  belongs_to :expert, polymorphic: true, count_cache: :expert_count
end

class Trainer
  has_many :questions, as: :expert
end

class Doctor
  has_many :questions, as: :expert
end
```

[Issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/16407) for setting counter_cache for polymorphic association is present for lower version of rails but you can deal with custom solution provided like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52903789/10522579)

Comment: What do you mean by `:expert_count`? @ray

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand what you mean by `:expert_count`. I want to be able to call `trainer.questions_count`. Is `:expert_count` going to do this? How? @ray

Comment: @jedi, it should work as per documentation when you try `@trainer.expert_count` as per doc provided, if it do not work you can work out with custom implementation like https://stackoverflow.com/a/15725387/10522579